# How to handle multiple dropboxes of the same name?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to have a series of dropboxes in my code, the number of dropboxes will be decided in a loop. Each dropbox reflects a different day, and each option in a dropbox a different time.

Only one of these times should be selectable by the user so that it can be passed on.

So my HTML will look as follows :

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="confirmation.cshtml">
   <select name="start_to_end_time" class="start_to_end_time">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <select name="start_to_end_time" class="start_to_end_time">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

With a changeable number of  tags. What is my best way to handle and validate this? I have tried doing so using JavaScript, and disabling all other days when one day is selected, this has resulted in errors however. Can anyone give me some help with this please?

Comment: If what you have tried resulted in "errors", you should let us know what the errors are!

Comment: you'll also need to change the action. 1. MVC points to controller actions, not views and 2. the client has no knowledge of the server technologies.

Comment: the naming convention is valid. it will create an array. ids must be unique, but names can be duplicated for simple values and the ms mvc framework.

Comment: you need to change the action as well. the action should point to a controller method, not a view. and the browser has no knowledge of the chosen server technologies. it doesn't know what the Razor templating engine is.

Comment: With respect, the best approach is to NOT give all your dropdowns the same name. Failing that, you can at least give them distinct IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to go a different route. I choose to add a class to the select list that I'm working on, and hide the others. Then I choose to capture the form submit, and monitor the amount of  objects that are held in our form at the time of post. if the # of objects is greater or less than 1, then I choose to provide an alert telling them to work with the form; else, if the length is equal to 1, process the form. I also commented out an example ajax request showing how to transfer the data to your controller. I think this is what you wanted to do -- or something along these lines? I could be wrong, and If I am, I stand corrected!

> http://jsfiddle.net/y6zLQ/4/

**for long term purpsoes**

```
$(function(){
  $("select").on('click', function(){
    //add a unique class identifier
    $(this).addClass('working');
    $("select:not('.working')").hide(100);
  });  
  $("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop default form submission
    var visLength = $("select:visible").length; //how many select fields are visible?
    if(visLength > 1 || visLength < 1){//if we have more/less than 1 visible field.
      alert('Please choose a value from the lists provided.');      
    }else if(visLength == 1){//we only have one field, proceed.
      var visValue = $("select:visible").val();
      alert(visValue);
     // $.ajax({
     //     url: 'confirmation.cshtml'      
     //     data: 'selectVal='+visValue,
     //     success: function(data){
     //       //do something with our returned data.
     //       $("#someElement").html(data);
     //       //or don't. Perhaps you want to change the page.
     //       window.location = 'mywebsite.com/newlocation';
     //     }
     // });
    }
  });    
  //build a reset function so they can choose a different date.    
  $("#reset").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop default form submission
    $("select").removeClass('working'); //remove unique class identifier
    $("select").show(100); //show other selec tlists
  });
});
```